# Issue with maven + surefire-plugin and Spring @Autowired

Tags: spring, maven-3, junit4, maven-surefire-plugin

I have been breaking my head in getting Spring `@Autowired` to work inside maven tests. When I run the JUnit tests inside IntellJ (did not try Eclipse) it works. But when I run mvn clean install, the JUnit tests fail with the following error

> testApp(com.sample.spring.AppTest): Error creating bean with name 'com.sample.spring.AppTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.sample.spring.AppB com.sample.spring.AppTest.appB; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.sample.spring.AppB] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

I have created a self contained sample project that exhibits this behaviour consistently. I am  using Spring 3.1.1. I am sure someone faced the same issue and cracked it. Looking for some pointers regarding this issue.

Comment: Here is the link to the source code

Comment: https://github.com/kuramach/testme

Answer (score 1):

This is a build path issue:

Working in eclipse I changed your ContextConfiguration to :

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:applicationContext.xml")
```

and it runs both with standard eclipse runner and maven(maven test or maven install).

Make sure you have:

> src/main/java
>
> src/test/java and
>
> src/test/resources

declared as source folders in your buildpath

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was breaking my head as well and realized that my src/test/resources was the issue. I had it at src/test/java/resources and you pointed that as well.